# Is there a way to replace some resources load by a web app and put others arbitrary ones?

Tags: flash, web-applications, internationalization, web, google-chrome-devtools

I have to do some inverse engineering in order to translate a flash web app.

By now, I can assume that all the strings are externalized in JSON URLs that I have identified.

So I wonder if is there a way to change this consumed JSONs for some arbitrary ones defined by me and check the above assumption.

I had the idea to shim the host with the help of the hosts file. But I can do this because I need to change only some resource like this:

www.example.com/externalized-strings.json

and not change all the resources under this domain.

I'm using Windos, Chrome and its dev tools for doing the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or another web debugging proxy.  Fiddler will let you create rules to change the URL of a request based on the properties of the request.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks with this "web debugging proxy" I google and also find [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).